# Problem with the Nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, ppa, gpu-driver

I just installed Ubuntu 18.10. I updated all the drivers and repositories besides adding another repository for the Nvidia graphics drivers. The problem is generated once I select the most recent version of the driver (415 open source code) of my GPU (750ti) at the time of restart when it starts changing the OS start resolution (load the start screen, the one that says Ubuntu with the five loading dots) and after that a black screen appears with what looks like a check of some kind which marks that everything is correct, but the loading of the OS gets stuck there and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's not so much a problem of the wrong graphics driver, rather that the Nvidia graphics driver has dependencies that are provided by the nvidia-driver-390 package in 18.04, 18.10, 19.04, 19.10, 20.04, 20.10, 21.04, 21.10 and 22.04, but not by ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa or whatever software source you installed version 415 of the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver from. The steps to follow are missing some information (which you should provide) depending on the source of version 415 of the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver that you installed, but basically they are as follows.

1. At the black screen where the boot process has stopped, open a text-only console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Now you are logged in to a text-only virtual console, and you can run terminal commands from the console.
5. Remove the software source of the existing Nvidia graphics driver. The `apt policy` command will show the name of the Nvidia graphics PPA that was added to your software sources if there is one. PPA names have the form `ppa:name-of-ppa/ppa` . Please comment if there is any doubt about the exact name of this PPA, and I will look it up online.

   ```
    sudo add-apt-repository --remove <ppa:name-of-ppa/ppa>
    sudo apt update
   ```
6. Remove the existing Nvidia graphics driver. The `ubuntu-drivers list` command will show the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver that is installed.

   ```
    sudo apt remove $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')
    sudo apt autoremove   
    sudo reboot
   ```
7. Install the Nvidia graphics driver from the default Ubuntu 18.10 repositories. The following two commands can be run from either the terminal or from a virtual console as before.

   ```
    sudo ubuntu-drivers install  
    sudo reboot
   ```

The `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` command installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies, and the Nvidia driver will also be updated automatically when an update is available.

Comment: And how do I enter the commands? from the terminal obviously but how do I open it while generating all that "report" at the beginning?

Comment: I replied to your comment by editing my answer.