# I learned autoremove killed my system

Tags: boot

I never autoremove from apt.  My NVIDIA drivers get angry.  I installed a program yesterday that did an autoremove in the script, now my desktop does not load.
I have an Ubuntu usb, how can i reinstall the drivers for my 1050ti without losing all the applications and cron jobs, etc...????

Comment: The list of removed packages is in /var/log/apt, so 1) Figure out how to read that list, then 2) Figure out which packages you want to reinstall, then 3) Tell apt to do so. There is no single magic incantation, you must be willing to learn, explore, and discover. You are about to learn how to use apt properly.

Comment: In future set your drivers to manually installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with the Nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111137/problem-with-the-nvidia-drivers)